# How to show SQLite database data in a recylerview list which is inside a fragment?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I am an amateur android developer and I would like to get user entered items from the database and then display it in a recyclerview list (not ListView) that is in a fragment.

So far I have already created the SQLite database which saves the data into it, I just want to know I can display all this information in the recyclerview. The Java code shown below shows what I want to make but is in a listview instead of a recyclerview.

**DatabaseHelper**

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String TAG = "DatabaseHelper";

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "budget10.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "expense_table";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME2 = "income_table";
    public static final String COL_1 = "_id";
    public static final String COL_2 = "_id";
    public static final String EXPENSE_AMOUNT = "EXPENSE_AMOUNT";
    public static final String EXPENSE_DATE = "DATE";
    public static final String EXPENSE_NOTES = "NOTES";
    public static final String INCOME_AMOUNT = "INCOME_AMOUNT";
    public static final String INCOME_DATE = "DATE";
    public static final String INCOME_NOTES = "NOTES";
    public static final String INCOME_CATEGORY = "INCOME_CATEGORY";
    public static final String EXPENSE_CATEGORY = "EXPENSE_CATEGORY";
    public static final String EXPENSE_ACCOUNT = "EXPENSE_ACCOUNT";
    public static final String INCOME_ACCOUNT = "INCOME_ACCOUNT";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 3);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + " (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, EXPENSE_AMOUNT DOUBLE,DATE INTEGER,NOTES TEXT, EXPENSE_CATEGORY TEXT, EXPENSE_ACCOUNT TEXT)");
        db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME2 + " (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,INCOME_AMOUNT DOUBLE,DATE INTEGER,NOTES TEXT, INCOME_CATEGORY TEXT, INCOME_ACCOUNT TEXT)");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME2);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean insertexpenseData(Double amount_expense, String date_expense, String notes_expense, String category_expense, String expense_account) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(EXPENSE_AMOUNT, amount_expense);
        contentValues.put(EXPENSE_DATE, date_expense);
        contentValues.put(EXPENSE_NOTES, notes_expense);
        contentValues.put(EXPENSE_CATEGORY, category_expense);
        contentValues.put(EXPENSE_ACCOUNT, expense_account);
        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
        if (result == -1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    public boolean insertincomeData(Double amount_income, String date_income, String notes_income, String category_income, String income_account) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(INCOME_AMOUNT, amount_income);
        contentValues.put(INCOME_DATE, date_income);
        contentValues.put(INCOME_NOTES, notes_income);
        contentValues.put(INCOME_CATEGORY, category_income);
        contentValues.put(INCOME_ACCOUNT, income_account);
        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME2, null, contentValues);
        if (result == -1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    public Cursor getexpenseData() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_NAME, null);
        return res;
    }

    public Cursor getincomeData() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_NAME2, null);
        return res;
    }



    public boolean updateexpenseData(String id, String amount, String date, String notes, String catagory_income) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_1, id);
        contentValues.put(EXPENSE_AMOUNT, amount);
        contentValues.put(EXPENSE_DATE, date);
        contentValues.put(EXPENSE_NOTES, notes);
        contentValues.put(EXPENSE_CATEGORY, catagory_income);
        db.update(TABLE_NAME, contentValues, "_id = ?", new String[]{id});
        return true;
    }

    public boolean updateincomeData(String id, String amount, String date, String notes, String catagory_income) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_2, id);
        contentValues.put(INCOME_AMOUNT, amount);
        contentValues.put(INCOME_DATE, date);
        contentValues.put(INCOME_NOTES, notes);
        contentValues.put(INCOME_CATEGORY, catagory_income);
        db.update(TABLE_NAME2, contentValues, "_id = ?", new String[]{id});
        return true;
    }

    public Integer deleteexpenseData(String _id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "_id = ?", new String[]{_id});
    }

    public Integer deleteincomeData(String _id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db.delete(TABLE_NAME2, "_id = ?", new String[]{_id});
    }

    public double getNetBudget() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT TOTAL(INCOME_AMOUNT) - (SELECT TOTAL(EXPENSE_AMOUNT) FROM expense_table) FROM income_table";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        double netBudget = 0.00; // if there is no row, this will mean 0 is returned. You could also set it to -1, or throw an Exception if no record is returned
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            netBudget = cursor.getDouble(0);
        }
        cursor.close();
        return netBudget;
    }

    public double getTotalExpense() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT TOTAL(EXPENSE_AMOUNT) FROM expense_table";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        double netExpense = 0.00; // if there is no row, this will mean 0 is returned. You could also set it to -1, or throw an Exception if no record is returned
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            netExpense = cursor.getDouble(0);
        }
        cursor.close();
        return netExpense;
    }

    public double getTotalIncome() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT TOTAL(INCOME_AMOUNT) FROM income_table";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        double netIncome = 0.00; // if there is no row, this will mean 0 is returned. You could also set it to -1, or throw an Exception if no record is returned
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            netIncome = cursor.getDouble(0);
        }
        cursor.close();
        return netIncome;
    }

    public void deleteAllIncome() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_NAME2, null, null);
        db.execSQL("delete from " + TABLE_NAME2);
        db.close();
    }

    public void deleteAllExpense() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_NAME, null, null);
        db.execSQL("delete from " + TABLE_NAME);
        db.close();
    }

}
```

**Fragment ListView that I want to turn into a recyclerview**

```
public class tab2income extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = "tab2income";
    DatabaseHelper mDatabaseHelper;
    private ListView mListView;
    View rootView;
    Cursor incomedata;
    SimpleCursorAdapter sca;
    DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("0.00");


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2income, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated( Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        mListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listViewincome);
        mListView.setEmptyView(rootView.findViewById(R.id.empty));
        mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());

        populateListView();
    }

    private void populateListView() {
        Log.d(TAG, "populateListView: Displaying data in the ListView.");
        incomedata = mDatabaseHelper.getincomeData();
        sca = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, incomedata, new String[]{DatabaseHelper.INCOME_AMOUNT}, new int[]{android.R.id.text1}, 0);
        mListView.setAdapter(sca);

        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                int csrpos = incomedata.getPosition();
                incomedata.moveToPosition(i);
                displayNoteDate(
                        incomedata.getString(incomedata.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.INCOME_NOTES)),
                        incomedata.getString(incomedata.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.INCOME_DATE)),
                        incomedata.getString(incomedata.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.INCOME_CATEGORY)),
                        l,
                        incomedata.getString(incomedata.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.INCOME_ACCOUNT)));
                incomedata.moveToPosition(csrpos);
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        incomedata.close();
    }

    public void displayNoteDate(String noteContent, String dateValue,String category, final long noteID,String account) {
        MaterialDialog.Builder builder= new MaterialDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .title("Income Information")
                .content("Date: "+ dateValue+
                        "\nCategory: "+category+
                        "\nAccount: "+account+
                        "\nNote: "+noteContent)
                .positiveText("close")
                .negativeText("delete")
                .onPositive(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
                    }
                })
                .onNegative(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
                        mDatabaseHelper.deleteincomeData(Long.toString(noteID));
                        incomedata = mDatabaseHelper.getincomeData();
                        sca.swapCursor(incomedata);
                    }
                });
        builder.show();
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

This is what I have done so far with the code in the answer from Saurov Bagchi and I have the recyclerview in my xml file and nothing happens when an item is clicked:

**Fragment**

```
public class tab2income extends Fragment implements ItemClickListener {

    private static final String TAG = "tab2income";
    DatabaseHelper mDatabaseHelper;
    private RecyclerView mListView;
    View rootView;
    Cursor incomedata;
    SimpleCursorAdapter sca;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2income, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        mListView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.ListViewincome);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        mListView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());

        populateListView();
    }

    private void populateListView() {
        Log.d(TAG, "populateListView: Displaying data in the ListView.");
        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(arrayList);
        mListView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

        incomedata = mDatabaseHelper.getincomeData();
        if(incomedata.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                arrayList.add(incomedata.getString(incomedata.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.INCOME_AMOUNT)));
            } while (incomedata.moveToNext());
        }
        myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        incomedata.close();
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view, int i) {
        int csrpos = incomedata.getPosition();
        incomedata.moveToPosition(i);
        displayNoteDate(
                incomedata.getString(incomedata.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.INCOME_NOTES)),
                incomedata.getString(incomedata.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.INCOME_DATE)),
                incomedata.getString(incomedata.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.INCOME_CATEGORY)),
                incomedata.getString(incomedata.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.INCOME_ACCOUNT)));
        incomedata.moveToPosition(csrpos);
    }

    public void displayNoteDate(String noteContent, String dateValue,String category,String account) {
        MaterialDialog.Builder builder= new MaterialDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .title("Income Information")
                .content("Date: "+ dateValue+
                        "\nCategory: "+category+
                        "\nAccount: "+account+
                        "\nNote: "+noteContent)
                .positiveText("close")
                .negativeText("delete")
                .onPositive(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
                    }
                })
                .onNegative(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
                    }
                });
        builder.show();
    }

}
```

**Adapter**

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private final ArrayList<String> dataSet;
    private ItemClickListener clickListener;

    public MyAdapter(ArrayList<String> myDataset) {
        dataSet = myDataset;
    }

    @Override
    public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        //layout of the list item
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.mTextView.setText(dataSet.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataSet.size();
    }

    public void setClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.clickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        final TextView mTextView;

        ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            //textview for showing results
            mTextView = v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            v.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        //for click
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (clickListener != null) clickListener.onClick(view, getAdapterPosition());

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you use new Android Architecture Components. It is easy and less code is required. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For RecyclerView you need to create your own custom Adapter.

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private final ArrayList<String> dataSet;
    private ItemClickListener clickListener;

    public MyAdapter(ArrayList<String> myDataset) {
        dataSet = myDataset;
    }

    @Override
    public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        //layout of the list item
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.mTextView.setText(dataSet.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataSet.size();
    }

    public void setClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.clickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        final TextView mTextView;

        ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            //textview for showing results
            mTextView = v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            v.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        //for click
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (clickListener != null) clickListener.onClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }
}
```

Then I am just rewriting the `populateListView()` method

```
private void populateListView() {
    Log.d(TAG, "populateListView: Displaying data in the ListView.");
    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(arrayList);
    mListView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

    incomedata = mDatabaseHelper.getincomeData();
    if(incomedata.moveToFirst()){
        do {
            arrayList.add(incomedata.getString(incomedata.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.INCOME_AMOUNT)));
        } while (incomedata.moveToNext());
    }
    myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

You also need to create an Interface for each Item Click.

```
public interface ItemClickListener {
    void onClick (View view, int position);
}
```

And implement this Interface in your Fragment.

```
public class tab2income extends Fragment implements ItemClickListener{

    //All of your codes

    @Override
    public void onClick (View view, int i) {
        int csrpos = incomedata.getPosition();
            incomedata.moveToPosition(i);
            displayNoteDate(
                    incomedata.getString(incomedata.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.INCOME_NOTES)),
                    incomedata.getString(incomedata.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.INCOME_DATE)),
                    incomedata.getString(incomedata.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.INCOME_CATEGORY)),
                    l,
                    incomedata.getString(incomedata.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.INCOME_ACCOUNT)));
            incomedata.moveToPosition(csrpos);
    }
}
```

Comment: I just wanted to ask how I would use this in a fragment?

Comment: What about the note ID, that does not work and also the constraint layout cardview also throws an error

Comment: Also, I tried fixing the exceptions and then running the application but the fragment does not show the recyclerview

Comment: The ViewHolder still remains red

Comment: I am getting this error "No layout manager attached; skipping layout" when I am opening my fragment

Comment: You have to attach a layout manager with RecyclerView. After `mListView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.ListViewincome);` line Add the following codes. `RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this); 
mListView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);`

Comment: I have done that and now I can see the layout but nothing happens when I click on one of the entries. You can see the current code in the updated code section in the question above.

Comment: Do you create `ItemClickListener` interface?
Also, add `mListView.setClickListener(this)` in your `populateListView()` method after setting the adapter.

Comment: That works now, I have one last question, You see in my code I have a dialog that opens when the recyclerview item is pressed, what if I want some of that information inside the dialog to show inside the same recyclerview row? like this:https://developer.android.com/design/material/images/list_mail.png

Comment: You are using the default layout android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 for each row. 
For styling row item. You need to create a custom layout for each row. Then modify the line `View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false)` and replace `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` with you layout.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158884/discussion-between-sourav-bagchi-and-deep-harquissandas).